# What will replace pyGTK tag?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

According to the [pygtk](/questions/tagged/pygtk) tag, and the Wikipedia article, PyGTK is for GTK2 and is being phased out. I'm wondering what tag will replace this, for questions that are based on the newer `gi.repository` imports and newer Python GTK code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [pygobject](/questions/tagged/pygobject) tag seems to be appropriate. Its wiki says:

> PyGObject is a Python module that provides bindings (through
>   introspection) for GObject and associated libraries, most notably
>   GTK+.

Or you could combine [python](/questions/tagged/python) and [gtk3](/questions/tagged/gtk3), as many questions do.